# Format to pass value into date-time picker

Tags: meteor, datetimepicker, meteor-autoform

Aldeeb's phenomenal [datetime picker](https://github.com/aldeed/meteor-autoform-bs-datetimepicker) has certainly saved me a lot of time (pun).

Only thing is... what format do I pass a value into it? I have a calendar control that should pass a date into this form. I tried passing a string `YYYY-MM-DD` format which didn't work. I then tried a date object via `Date('YYYY-MM-DD')` which also didn't work. The input works, as expected. It just doesn't have the expected value.

If I change this from `bootstrap-datetimepicker` in my schema and just leave it as a `String`, it has the correct value, so I know the info is getting there.

Just need to know what format to pass it in as.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'm dumb.

Just worked with the string value `YYYY-MM-DD` despite the schema type being `Date`. One smart plugin, not certain what I did wrong before.